# Dropbox creates conflicted copy of TrueCrypt container on read access (no modification)

Tags: truecrypt, dropbox

I use TrueCrypt containers in Dropbox with `preserve modification timestamp` option unchecked. This enables Dropbox to know that the file has been modified and it should be sync'd.

Unfortunately, TrueCrypt updates the timestamp of the container on read access also. If I have multiple devices reading the container, Dropbox thinks that all of them have modified the file. This ends up in Dropbox creating conflicted copies.

Question :

- Is there a way I can tell TrueCrypt to update timestamp only when I modify files in the container. That's what I ideally want.

OR

- Can I tell dropbox to compare contents of the file before creating conflicted copies, not just based on timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you mounting the TrueCrypt container as "read-only" or not?

If not then there is no way to avoid the conflicted copies.

When mounting the container in full-access the access-time and date of the files you browse (in the filesystem) are always changed (within the container). This will result in **a change in container-file**. You can check this by doing a file-compare on the container (and copy) after mounting and dismounting (with fc.exe or other utility). Any change in the container will result in an upload by Dropbox. When multiple machines have the file open you get the conflicted copies.

The only way around this might be to open the container as "read-only".
(In that case you can't change any files. When you need to change files you need to dismount and mount the container again with full-access)

In the Windows-version you can choose `Volumes`, `Mount Volume with Options`.
Then choose `Mount volume as read-only`:

[image]

Edit:

You can set the "read-only" as default for all future mounts. When you need to change files you can use the method above to mount with full-access (by unticking the box). To set "read-only" as default choose `Settings`, `Preferences` and tick `Mount volumes as read-only`.

[image]

Edit 2:

Even if you can set Windows to **not** update the file-system (and effectively the container) on access of a file (for the access-timestamp) TrueCrypt itself updates the container also when mounting as not read-only. See this image of a container right after mounting it (78KB written) with full-access without even accessing it:
(so there is no point in looking at the access-timestamp as TrueCrypt itself updates the container too) So you're only left with the read-only option.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this works. Just have to be careful while mounting volumes. Could you elaborate on the logic behind `When mounting the container in full-access the access-time and date of the files you browse (in the filesystem) are always changed (within the container)`

Comment: That's why maybe you should set the default as read-only and only deselect it when needed (i know... it's a pain). When you **read** a file-system and **open files** Windows [keeps a record of the last access-timestamp of the file accessed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee681827(v=vs.85).aspx). This is stored in the file-system. So even when accessing files (without changing them) the container will change. I'm not sure if TrueCrypt itself also has some logging it stores in the file but since Windows definitively changes it it won't matter.

Comment: BTW. According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee681827(v=vs.85).aspx) NTFS does not store the access-timestamp with the file itself but has a separate logging mechanism (within the file-system, so still in the container). I haven't tried it yet but maybe if you disable the logging of file-access in NTFS it could help from changing the container. After that you should check if TrueCrypt itself doesn't do anything to the file (or else you right back where you started:)

Comment: See my "Edit #2": Even if you can set Windows to **not** update the file-system (and effectively the container) on access of a file (for the access-timestamp) TrueCrypt itself updates the container also when mounting as not read-only. See my image of the container right after mounting it (78KB written) with full-access without even accessing it:  
(so there is no point in looking at the access-timestamp as TrueCrypt itself updates the container too) So you're only left with the read-only option.